# accelerate DEAP using multiprocessing report OSError

Tags: python, multiprocessing, deap

I want to accelerate DEAP using multiprocessing but always get OSError. Here is abbreviated version of my code:

```
import operator
import math
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    
from deap import algorithms
from deap import base
from deap import creator
from deap import tools
from deap import gp
import multiprocessing

# protectedDiv
def protectedDiv(left, right):
    try:
        return left / right
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 1

# omitting some other functions

creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", gp.PrimitiveTree, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

# here is DEAP strong typed GP setting
pset = gp.PrimitiveSetTyped("MAIN", [np.ndarray] * 12, np.ndarray)
pset.addPrimitive(operator.add, [np.ndarray, np.ndarray], np.ndarray)
pset.addPrimitive(operator.sub, [np.ndarray, np.ndarray], np.ndarray)
pset.renameArguments(ARG0='close')
pset.renameArguments(ARG1='open')

# here is fitness function. My goal is maximum stock return's ICIR.
def evalSymbReg(individual):
    # omitting code
    return icir,

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("expr", gp.genHalfAndHalf, pset=pset, min_=1, max_=3)
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initIterate, creator.Individual, toolbox.expr)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)
toolbox.register("compile", gp.compile, pset=pset)

toolbox.register("evaluate", evalSymbReg)
toolbox.register("select", tools.selTournament, tournsize=10)
toolbox.register("mate", gp.cxOnePoint)
toolbox.register("expr_mut", gp.genFull, min_=0, max_=2)
toolbox.register("mutUniform", gp.mutUniform, expr=toolbox.expr_mut, pset=pset)
toolbox.decorate("mate", gp.staticLimit(key=operator.attrgetter("height"), max_value=10))
toolbox.decorate("mutUniform", gp.staticLimit(key=operator.attrgetter("height"), max_value=10))

def main():
    n_sample = 5000
    n_gen = 40
    cxpb = 0.6
    mutUniformpb = 0.4

    pop = toolbox.population(n=n_sample)
    hof = tools.HallOfFame(10)

    stats_fit = tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
    stats_size = tools.Statistics(len)
    mstats = tools.MultiStatistics(fitness=stats_fit, size=stats_size)
    mstats.register("avg", np.nanmean)
    mstats.register("min", np.nanmin)
    mstats.register("max", np.nanmax)

    pop, log = algorithms.my_eaSimple(pop, toolbox, cxpb, mutUniformpb, mutNodeReplacementpb, mutEphemeralpb, mutShrinkpb,
                                      n_gen, stats=mstats, halloffame=hof, verbose=True)

    # print log
    return pop, log, hof, info, top10

# here is my data file.
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\xxyao\research\国债期货\data\data_summary.csv')
df['pct-1'] = df['close'].pct_change().shift(-1)
df['month'] = [x[0:7] for x in df['date']]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6)
    toolbox.register('map', pool.map)
    pop, log, hof, info, top10 = main()
```

When I run the code I got error message like this:

[image]

This message repeated show in the window quickly. I don't know where is wrong. I protect the `Pool()` in `__name__ == __main__` as DEAP document says. But it still can't work. Can somebody help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the `main` and the function will work.

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6)
toolbox.register('map', pool.map)
```